# Files.walk - filter files which exist only in a given list

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following code:

```
// ArrayList<String> fileNameList already exists by this time
// myConsolidatedMapEntries is a Hashmap

try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(fileSourcePath))) {
            paths
            .filter(Files::isReadable)
            .filter(file -> file.toString().endsWith(".dat"))
            .forEach((Path filePath) -> {
                myConsolidatedMapEntries.putAll(processFile(myServicePath, filePath));//processFile returns a hashmap
            });
} catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Instead of the existing filter where it reads all files of a specific type, I need a new filter that checks for the files that exist in a specific ArrayList.

I have an ArrayList of file names and I need to filter/consider only those files in this directory whose names are in that list of names.

```
.filter(file -> file.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(fileNameList)
--> I am showing this only for representation. I know it is wrong.
```

I am trying to see if I can put this condition in the lambda. Is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: @vphilipnyc I'll check this as well but the below answer is simple and works for me.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.  It works best to map from `Path` to `File` and then see if the list contains the file name.

```
List<String> fileList = List.of("file1.txt", "file3.dat");
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get(fileSourcePath))) {
    paths
    .filter(Files::isReadable)
    .map(Path::toFile)
    .filter(file -> fileList.contains(file.getName()))
    .forEach(file->System.out.println(file));       
}catch (IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Just to note, in case it applies to someone's situation, that `Path#toFile()` is documented to work only for the _default_ `FileSystem`.

Comment: Yes, this works...Thank you! I am surprised that I missed such a basic point.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```java
file -> fileNameList.contains(file.getName())
```

?

If you need to sanitize filenames, then, you'd just tack that on. Something like `file.getName().toLowerCase()`. Or, if there's more you need to do, then maybe define how you want to sanitize/standardize the filenames for comparison, and then call that, like: `fileNameList.contains(sanitize(file.getName()))`

(caveat: haven't run this)